# How to aggregate messages with the identical headers in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(Main.class);
    ctx.refresh();
    DirectChannel channel1 = ctx.getBean("channel1", DirectChannel.class);

    ctx.getBean("channel2", PublishSubscribeChannel.class).subscribe(message ->
           System.out.println("Output: " + message));

    channel1.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("p1")
        .setHeader(CORRELATION_ID, 1)
        .setHeader(SEQUENCE_SIZE,2)
        .setHeader(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,1)
        .setHeader("a", 1)
        .build());

    channel1.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("p2")
        .setHeader(CORRELATION_ID, 1)
        .setHeader(SEQUENCE_SIZE,2)
        .setHeader(SEQUENCE_NUMBER,2)
        .setHeader("a", 2)
        .build());
}

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel1() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel channel2() {
        return MessageChannels.publishSubscribe().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("channel1")
                .aggregate(a -> a
                        .releaseStrategy(new SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy())
                        .expireGroupsUponCompletion(true)
                        .sendPartialResultOnExpiry(true))
                .channel("channel2")
                .get();
    }
```

**Output: GenericMessage [payload=[p1, p2], headers={sequenceNumber=2, a=2, correlationId=1, id=b5e51041-c967-1bb4-1601-7e468ae28527, sequenceSize=2, timestamp=1580475773518}]**

Headers "a" and "sequenceNumber" were overwritten.
How to aggregate messages with the identical headers?

It must be so

**Output: GenericMessage [payload=[p1, p2], headers={sequenceNumber=[1,2], a=[1, 2], correlationId=1, id=b5e51041-c967-1bb4-1601-7e468ae28527, sequenceSize=2, timestamp=1580475773518}]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor`:

```
/**
 * Specify a {@link Function} to map {@link MessageGroup} into composed headers for output message.
 * @param headersFunction the {@link Function} to use.
 * @since 5.2
 */
public void setHeadersFunction(Function<MessageGroup, Map<String, Object>> headersFunction) {
```

and also:

```
/**
 * The {@link Function} implementation for a default headers merging in the aggregator
 * component. It takes all the unique headers from all the messages in group and removes
 * those which are conflicted: have different values from different messages.
 *
 * @author Artem Bilan
 *
 * @since 5.2
 *
 * @see AbstractAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor
 */
public class DefaultAggregateHeadersFunction implements Function<MessageGroup, Map<String, Object>> {
```

Or just long existing:

```
/**
 * This default implementation simply returns all headers that have no conflicts among the group. An absent header
 * on one or more Messages within the group is not considered a conflict. Subclasses may override this method with
 * more advanced conflict-resolution strategies if necessary.
 * @param group The message group.
 * @return The aggregated headers.
 */
protected Map<String, Object> aggregateHeaders(MessageGroup group) {
```

So, what you need in your `aggregate()` configuration is an `outputProcessor(MessageGroupProcessor outputProcessor)` option.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregatingmessagehandler